# How to make phone input with country code in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

[For reference you can see this image I need something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ox2N.png)

I am new and learning React JS and I want to take the phone input in +917896541230 or +91 78965412330 in this format, not in this +91 (123)789 654 0 or not in any other format  ("I gave +91 as a exam of country code but it will accept all countries code around the world")  because then number stored in the database is in above format. I try to include jQuery but it did not work. I don't understand How to do this the npm packages I got all are in a different format which does not work for me.

This is my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import firebase from './firebase'
import "./App.css";
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
// import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'

class Login extends React.Component {

    // jQuery code
   
    // var phoneNumber = window.intlTelInput(document.querySelector("#phoneNumber"), {
    //         separateDialCode: true,
    //         preferredCountries:["in"],
    //         hiddenInput: "full",
    //         utilsScript: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.3/js/utils.js"
    //         });
           
    //         $("#getCode").click(function() {
    //         var full_num = phoneNumber.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164);
    //         $("input[name='phoneNumber[full]'").val(full_num);
        
    //         localStorage.setItem("Phone_No", full_num) 
    //         });
    //       
  handleChange = (e) =>{
    const {name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
      })
      this.setState({ phoneNumber: value }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.phoneNumber);
      });
  }
  configureCaptcha = () =>{
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {

        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.

        this.onSignInSubmit();
        // console.log("Recaptca varified")
      },
      //  defaultCountry: "IN"
     }
    );
  }
  onSignInSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.configureCaptcha()
    const phoneNumber =  this.state.mobile
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
    get(child(dbRef, `Users/${phoneNumber}`)).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()){
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
   
        .then((confirmationResult) => {

          // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
          // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
           
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        
          alert('An OTP has been sent to your registered mobile number')
          localStorage.setItem("Phone_No", phoneNumber ) 
          console.log(localStorage.getItem('Phone_No'));

        
        }).catch((error) => {
          
          console.error(error);
          alert("Oops! Some error occured. Please try again.")
        });
      }
      else{
        alert('Sorry, this mobile number is not registered with us. Please use your registered mobile number.');
      }
      
  }) 
  }
  onSubmitOTP = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const code = this.state.otp
    console.log(code)
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then((result) => {
      // User signed in successfully.
      const Users = result.user;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Users)) 
      this.props.history.push("/home");
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert("You have entered wrong code")
     });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Main-header">
      <img src="./55k-logo.png" alt="Company Logo" style={{height: "80px", width: "200px"}} />
      <br/>
      <div>
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <p>Limtless Water. From Unlimited Air.</p>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSignInSubmit}>
          <div id="sign-in-button"></div>
          {/* <PhoneInput */}

          <label>Mobile Number</label> <br/>
          {/* for="phoneNumber"  */}
       
          <input type="tel" id="phone" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Number" required onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <div className="buttons">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitOTP}>
        <label >Code</label> <br/>  
        {/* for="code" */}
        
          <input type="number" name="otp" placeholder="Enter The 6 Digit OTP" required onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <div className="buttons" >
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: Would the acceptable phone numbers _always_ be prefixed with an Indian country code?

Comment: No it accept all countries code

Comment: You need to give us some background on all the different types of numbers you want to match.

Comment: I want any user around the world can use this by selecting there country and number format should be like +19876543321 or +1 9876543221 I give +1 country code as example but it accept all the country code in the world

Answer (score 0):

try React Moduel
first install package

1. npm i react-phone-input-2
   second require it on page
2. import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2'
   third import css
3. import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css'

in side return (
<PhoneInput
country={"in"}

/>
)